# I cant call my constructor method SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new at the android studio. I tried creating SQLite Database but when I try inserting data android studio cannot resolve it. i also tried MainActivity.this and getApplicationContext instead of `db=new DatabaseHelper(this);` on this line. and on device monitor, it isn't creating a database file

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.lenovo.sqlite_2_deneme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.midi.MidiDevice;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        EditText et_name,et_surname,et_number;
        Button btn_data;

        et_name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_isim);
        et_surname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_soyisim);
        et_number= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_numara);
        btn_data= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_veri);

        btn_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.insertData();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

and my DatabaseHelper class

```
package com.example.lenovo.sqlite_2_deneme;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.TableLayout;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "student_info.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="student_table";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="NAME";
    public static final String COL_3="SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4="NUMBER";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+ TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, NUMBER INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public Boolean DataInsert(String name, String surname, String number)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,number);

        long sonuc= db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

        if(sonuc==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: there is no method  name `db.insertData();` inside your `DatabaseHelper`

Answer (score 0):

Your database will be created at the instance when you call

```
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
```

At the moment I dont see you have called this anywhere in your code. You have written a DataInsert method but it is not getting called in the code you have shared so far.

Comment: I noticed that but I couldn't try because of launch break if I correct that does it create database

Comment: Yes it will. You call your DataInsert instead of insertDat method and it should work

Comment: Thanks I'll try it after launch but without DataInsert method it didn't create database

Comment: You can create DB by calling the getWritableDatabase method before inserting into DB if you want that

Answer (score 0):

> There is no method **`insertData()`** . You should use
>   **`DataInsert()`** method .

```
   db=new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

    EditText et_name,et_surname,et_number;
    Button btn_data;

    et_name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_isim);
    et_surname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_soyisim);
    et_number= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_numara);
    btn_data= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_veri);

    btn_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            db.DataInsert(et_name.getText().toString(),et_surname.getText().toString(),et_number.getText().toString());

        }
    });
```

**FYI**

```
void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db)
```

> Called when the database is created for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

your'e sql query is wrong give the space in table (insert data),and also in onupgrade and **there is no method insertData()**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, NUMBER INTEGER)");
```